# Is the inverse of a continuous bijection on a compact connected set continous??

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose you have a compact connected metric space A and another  metric space B.Given a continuous bijection F from A to a subset of B is the inverse of F also a continuous function .

Also can the intitial conditions be relaxed (as in does a continuous bijection from a just a connected metric space A to a subset of B have an inverse which is continuous )

Comment: Any map $f:X\to Y$ that is invertible and continuous with $X$ compact and $Y$ Hausdorff is a homeomorphism on its image.

Comment: Metric spaces are Hausdorff.

Comment: Closed subsets of compact spaces are compact, continuous images of compact spaces are compact, compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed. Hence $f(C)$ is closed for each $C$ closed in $X$.